# PHP View-Controller-Class Model

Tags: php, javascript

I have an open ended question for PHP View-Controller-Class model.

Say, we have to perform logic loop in controller to use method in class to retrieve data row from database.

However, at anyone time, I can set 1 PHP variable in view to display the content. I need help to understand how to display data in nicely tabulated HTML format from controller.

I know one way is to use Javascript

```
$(#div_id).html(variable_embedded_html_coding);
```

All advise would be very much appreciated.

Comment: if you want a table use `<table></table>` in your view i think you are thinking about grid control???

Comment: I don't understand why you can set only 1 variable? Controller assigns variables to views so it can be more that one. Do you use your own framework? Also check this link http://phpgrid.com You can pass many variables with JSON or XML

Comment: That's just an example. It suppose to output values via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

To have nicely looked table you can use phpgrid.com

[image: Php grid]

To send message from php to js having more than 1 variable. You can use for example **JSON** or **xml**. To encode array in php to json format use **json_encode();** In Ajax you should change your datatype to **JSON**.

so from JS side you should do something like this

```
var request = $.ajax({
 url: "script.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: {id : menuId}, //it'll be in $_POST['id']
 dataType: "json"
}).done(function(msg){
  $("#your_div").html(msg.html);
  //msg.othervariable is also possible here
});
```

from php(script.php)

```
$arr = array('html'=> "<p>asdasd</p>", othervariable=>"it works");
echo json_encode($arr);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of your variable (probably an array) you can create a helper function which you can call from your view layer. The function will take your original variable and output it as a HTML table.

e.g. something like:

```
tabHelper.php

function print_tab($var)
{
    $tab = '<table>'."\n";
    foreach ($var as $row) {
        $tab .= '<tr><td>'.$row.'</td></tr>'."\n";
    }

    $tab .= '</table>';
    echo $tab;
}
```

and then in your view you would call:

```
<?php include_once ('tabHelper.php'); ?>

...

<?php print_tab($my_variable); ?>
```

You could even extend the helper to be able to pass additional attributes, such as class, id, etc.

Comment: is tabHelper.php a standalone file? Can I put that print_tab function in my controller? How can I use it with my controller file?

Comment: That is just an example code. You can put the `print_tab` function anywhere you want in fact ;) If you want to stick to MVC though you should keep the controller logic and view logic separated, so you shouldn't use the printing function inside or together with your controller. Inside the controller you can prepare the array with data and in the view print it out to the browser.